# '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

имеется функция которая считывает количество слов в тексте

```
def count_words(text):
    words_list = text.split()
    return len(words_list)
```

нужно с помощью функции считать кол-во слов в файле

```
from my_lib import count_words
open_text = open("lorem_hm.txt" , "r")
a = open_text.read()
b = count_words(a)
open_text.close
print(a)
```

он выводит просто текст / но не кол-во слов

буду благодарен за подсказки

Comment: Ну так результат подсчета у вас в переменной b, а выводите вы переменную a.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо поменять код на этот в связи с тем, что у вас происходит операция подсчёта количества слов с переменной 'a' и сохраняете в 'b', но выводите переменную 'a', а нужно выводить 'b':

```
from my_lib import count_words
open_text = open("lorem_hm.txt" , "r")
a = open_text.read()
b = count_words(a)
open_text.close
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from my_lib import count_words
open_text = open("lorem_hm.txt" , "r")
r = count_words(open_text.read())
open_text.close
print(r)
```

решил, спасибо большое за подсказки и спасибо человеку который удалил комент) не успел поблагодарить

Comment: Вы вопрос изменили после того как я ответил. Фактически проблема озвученная в заголовке больше не воспроизводится, поэтому я удалил ответ. А то что вы не из той переменной данные выводите - для меня это слишком мелкая проблема, чтобы по ней целый ответ писать.